# Does HTML Purifier (which converts & to &amp;) prevent HTTP parameter pollution?

Tags: web-application, http, webserver

If a REST endpoint (http://example.com) reads the `p` query parameter and pass it along to another endpoint:

```
http_get("http://example.com/api2?p=".$_GET['p']);
```

I will be able to exploit it by appending content after `p`: http://example.com?p=a%26admin=true, which will cause it to make a request to http://example.com/api2?p=a&admin=true (`%26` is decoded to `&` by the server), which will result in an exploit if the `/api2` endpoint reads the `admin` parameter.

However, if I use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) on `$_GET['p']`, it will convert `&` into `&amp;`, which will break the attack unless api2 reads `amp;admin` (which is not likely in practice).

Does that mean the escape of `&` into `&amp;` will effectively prevent the exploit? Why does [this page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_HTTP_Parameter_pollution_(OTG-INPVAL-004)) warn us to watch out for `&amp;HPP_TEST` then?

Comment: I fail to understand the question. HTML Purifier is used to sanitize user provided HTML before it gets included in some HTML page in order to protect client against XSS or similar. HTTP parameter pollution is done by calling a specifically prepared URL in order to confuse parameter checking by the server. HTML purifying cannot be applied against HTTP parameter pollution simply because there is no HTML involved in the latter.

Comment: Also, calling i.e. HTML purifier on some URL makes no sense since the URL is no HTML either. It might even garble the URL, i.e. transform `query?foo=1&bar=2` to `query?foo=1&amp;bar=2` which will then result in parameter `amp;bar=2` instead of `bar=2`

Comment: It's not called against the entire url, only the query parameter `purify($_GET['p'])`, which effectively prevent against parameter pollution by ensuring additional parameters are not added when it's only expecting a single one.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I think you should make that an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP parameter pollution is the process of manipulating a URL in order to bypass parameter validation at the server or WAF. It is for example done by adding one parameter again, i.e. making the query string `foo=1&bar=2` to `foo=1&bar=2&bar=bad-value`.

Note that a polluted URL is still a valid URL and that it might even be intended that way, for example by using web form with multiple input fields having the same field name. Because of this any kind of HTTP parameter pollution protection needs to know what kind of URL or parameters are actually expected.

The use case for HTML purifier is a completely different one: sanitize user-provided HTML before it gets included in some server generated HTML. A HTML purifier has has no idea of how the valid URL in the context of the application should look like and thus cannot help to protect against HTTP parameter pollution.

But using it could actually make the problem worse: for example if the query string of the URL has the parameters `foo=1&bar=2` converting this to HTML will result in `foo=1&amp;bar=2` which will result in getting a parameter `amp;bar=2` extracted instead of the expected `bar=2`.

Comment: There is another kind of parameter pollution as I highlighted in the post: `foo=1%26bar=2`, `$_GET('foo')` will read it as `foo=1&bar=2` (`bar=2` is unintended), but with `purify($_GET('foo'))` it'll be read as `foo=1&amp;bar=2`, which is safe.

Comment: @Avery235: A HTML purifier will not change `foo=1%26bar=2` to `foo=1&bar=2`. If it would do this it would actually break the intended value for the parameter foo which is `1&bar=2`, i.e. `foo=%26a=1&bar=2`  should result in `foo` being `&a=1` and `bar` being `2` and not `foo` being empty, `a` being `1`and `bar` being `2`. There is a valid reason to URL-encode '&', namely to distinguish it from the parameter separator `&`. BTW, you might try your input [here](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php).

Comment: That was not my claim. I'm saying the purifier will change `foo=1&bar=2` into `foo=1&amp;bar=2`. The extra `bar=2` is injected by the attacker, but rendered harmless by the purifier (as it's now `amp;bar=2`).

Comment: @Avery235: I know understand what you mean. You essentially misuse HTML purifier in order to convert `&` into something else in the hope that the result will not only break the parameter pollution (it does, at least if the parameter you expect does not start with `amp;` itself) but also not cause any harmful side effects due to some unexpected parameters (this depends on your specific application). Anyway, I think this is a misuse of what HTML purifier is intended. It would be much better just to check for an `&` in the parameter and in this case abort the processing due to invalid input.

Comment: I don't intend to do this in an actual app. This is a school assignment in which we are asked to describe why there is a HPP vulnerability, which I believe there isn't due to the use of `purify`. Well I guess from an academic standpoint you could claim that the other endpoint might be specifically reading `amp;bar`...

Answer (score 0):

The reason OWASP warns to look for `&amp;HPP_TEST` is because it is a symptom of **CLIENT-SIDE** hpp vulnerability. The attack you are describing is against **SERVER-SIDE** hpp. These are two entirely different things.

So what is client-side hpp? Consider if I send to you a link such as:

`www.example.com?name=avery%26action=delete`.

Now the site will generate html for that link. For example it might have `<a>` tags that depend on the parameters. If the site isn't vulnerable it might send back something harmless like

`<a href="http://www.example.com/showMessage?name=avery%26action=delete">View</a>`

But if the site is vulnerable it might instead send back html like either:

`<a href="http://www.example.com/showMessage?name=avery&action=delete">View</a>`

`<a href="http://www.example.com/showMessage?name=avery&amp;action=delete">View</a>`

So what's happened is the server has been manipulated into creating a link that has extra parameters. Now if you use www.example as you normally would, you might click on the link to find you've somehow been tricked into deleting your own data. OWASP is basically warning you to check if your server creates this sort of HTML from URL parameters.

As for if it is secure to use HTML purifier as a way to prevent against server-side hpp; I will say that yes it will work for your one case but it isn't that great a solution as it means you'll never be able to create any functions requiring more than one parameter. It is better to do proper URL encoding and input validation.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty redundant attack. You could have just sent me http://www.example.com/showMessage?name=avery&action=delete directly (instead of http://www.example.com?name=avery%26action=delete).

Comment: The example is the simplest <a> tag to demonstrate the concept. The real danger is that it is easy to hide the fact that the website is compromised and because it is the user that initiates the action. This allows an attacker to bypass things such as authentication controls and CSRF protections. It's also possible to contaminate POST calls or other complicated client-sided ajax in which you can't just send a bad link directly.

Comment: Anyway the point is the part of the OWASP docs you ask about is referring to client-side HPP.